# How to define subidform

Tags: racket, scribble

In racket, we have `defsubform` for subform, but `defsubform` does not accept a form like `bar` but only `(bar ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a (cleaned-up) [implementation of `defsubform`](https://github.com/racket/scribble/blob/7292c39f6a545868f0dc6a6821b74e62af93ba6a/scribble-lib/scribble/private/manual-form.rkt#L203)

```
#lang racket

(require scribble/core
         scribble/decode)

(define (into-blockquote s)
  (make-nested-flow (make-style "leftindent" null)
                    (if (splice? s)
                        (decode-flow (splice-run s))
                        (list s))))

(define-syntax (defsubform stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ . rest) #'(into-blockquote (defform . rest))]))
```

This suggests that you can implement `defsubidform` as follows:

```
(define-syntax (defsubidform stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    [(_ . rest) #'(into-blockquote (defidform . rest))]))
```

Comment: Do you think this is worth adding back into scribble?